# como acessar propriedades não padrão javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá, faço uma requisição xml, e recebo uma tag chamada item, com alguns atributos não convencionais

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType: 'text',
    url : "requests/playlist_jstree.xml",
    success: function(retorno){
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(retorno,"text/xml");
        var lista=xmlDoc.getElementById("plid_2").getElementsByTagName("item");
        console.log(xmlDoc.getElementById("plid_5").uri);
    }, 
    error: function(e){

    }
});
```

Essa plid_5 está dentro da plid_2, eu podia ter acessado ela assim também:

```
console.log(lista[0].uri
```

Mas nenhum dos dois consegue acessar esse atributo chamado uri, na verdade o unico atributo que funciona é o id, os outros atributos nao acessam, como faço pra acessar o valor desses atributos?

Comment: O que dá `console.log(retorno);`?

Comment: Abra o console do browser e escreva código js diretamente lá. Você pode inclusive inspecionar a variável `lista` e ver todo o seu conteúdo, métodos e atributos.

Comment: JS é uma linguagem de [duck typing](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), o que significa que a linguagem não se importa com assinaturas/conteúdos fortes, tudo vai depender de como o objeto foi construído e alimentado

Answer (score 0):

Se você se refere aos atributos representados no XML, você acessa eles similiarmente como na classe atual `HTMLElement`.

```
let elem = xmlDoc.getElementById `plid_5`

console.log(
    elem.attributes.uri.value,
    elem.attributes[índice].value,
    elem.getAttribute `uri`
)
```